# How to prevent network requests in unit test mode?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

This is not about mocking the network requests. As the unit test framework actually starts the app at the beginning of the unit tests, the list I'm showing after startup is causing a Network request. So I want to prevent the app of making those regular networking calls after startup when the app is in unit test mode.

Comment: Must the app be able to make normal network requests ***during*** startup, or  not ever at all?

Comment: You can create a scheme for testing and order that scheme to not run the app on startup under "profile" section

Comment: In Unit test mode I don‘t need any real network calls at all. But I‘m not sure whether disabling the startup of the app is a good solution as there must be a reason Apple does that.

Comment: I‘m basically looking for some sort of compiler directive to check whether the app is in test mode. Then I can wrap those calls. So something like #if DEBUG would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the app running the test.
Here are an extension and an example for you.

```
extension Thread {
  var isRunningXCTest: Bool {
    for key in self.threadDictionary.allKeys {
      guard let keyAsString = key as? String else {
        continue
      }

      if keyAsString.split(separator: ".").contains("xctest") {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
if Thread.current.isRunningXCTest {
  // test code goes here
  // prevent from requests.
} else {
  // other code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, altough this would probably work, I went for the solution using a launch argument.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went for a clean and easy solution: setting the launch argument "-isInTestMode" in the "Test" Scheme and checking it using the bellow global function:

[image]

```
func isRunningTests: Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isInTestMode")
}
```